# Getting data from json without object from url android. I got errors

Tags: android, json

I want to get some data from a URL. The JSON data does not contain any object.

My code:

```
requestQueuee = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JsonObjectRequest obreqqw = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,kl,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                 String name= json.getString("FRUITS");
                 hu(name);
                }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volley", "Error");
        }
    }
);
//Toast.makeText (this, desc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

requestQueuee.add(obreqqw);
```

My log:

> [4219] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for ....

Comment: check your url in browser...what is the response.

Comment: url is correct and i get json file.But it does  not have any object.it has only string.can you give me the code to get string without object?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, you are not using your response in the response callback...

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
String name= json.getString("FRUITS");
```

`name` will always be null